# Obtener comentarios de páginas desde Facebook4j api

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-api

Estoy intentando obtener los comentarios de los post de la página de "el país" y creo que se hace con `PagableList<Comment> comments = post.getComments();` pero me sale `null` en todos los resultados.

¿Sabéis cómo se sacarían los resultados de los comentarios usando esta librería?

```
public class FacebookDAO{
    Facebook facebook = new FacebookFactory().getInstance();

    //Método para buscar post en facebook según la identificación de la página
    public JSONArray buscarPost(String buscar) {

        JSONArray jarray = new JSONArray();
        try {
            ResponseList<Post> feeds = facebook.getFeed("elpaisespana", new Reading().limit(15));
            for (int i = 0; i < feeds.size(); i++) {

                Post post = feeds.get(i);
                String message = post.getMessage();
                //Sacar comentarios
                PagableList<Comment> comments = post.getComments();

                //Guardar en JSON
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
                obj.put("Fecha", post.getCreatedTime());
                obj.put("Id", post.getId());
                obj.put("Likes", post.getLikes());
                obj.put("Mensaje", post.getMessage());

                for (int j = 0; j < comments.size; j++) {
                    obj.put("Comentario", post.getComments());
                }

                jarray.add(obj);
            }
        } catch (FacebookException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(jarray);
        return jarray;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sí he visto la página de Facebook4j y el javadoc

Comment: Tienes que poner correctamente el id de la página que quieres leer: `facebook.getFeed("elpaisespana"...` ¿seguro que el id de la página es ese?

Comment: Seguro, es la página de el país